# R object not found error despite it exists in the data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame in which the variables were calculated by using the unite function in R dyplr. When I load the new data frame, all the variables are there as they should be; however, when trying to further work with it and index it by using the mutate function I get an error saying:! object 'inverted_facing' not found. I tried renaming the variables, but they are not found by the rename function either. All the online advice talks about either forgetting to create the variables or misspelling them in the code, but this is not the case. They are in the data frame and they are spelled correctly in the code. Why are they not found? Can anyone help with fixing this?

Data Frame:

```
> subj_means_index_Acc
# A tibble: 100 × 7
# Groups:   subject, site, category [100]
   subject site  category  `inverted_facing   ` inverted_nonFacing `upright _facing   ` `upright _nonFacing`
   <chr>   <chr> <chr>                    <dbl>              <dbl>                <dbl>                <dbl>
 1 P01     EBA   "chairs "                0.875              0.969                0.969                1    
 2 P01     EBA   "targets"                0.656              0.75                 0.906                1    
 3 P01     OPA   "chairs "                0.969              1                    0.906                0.969
 4 P01     OPA   "targets"                0.469              0.688                0.906                0.969
 5 P02     EBA   "chairs "                0.906              0.875                0.938                0.906
 6 P02     EBA   "targets"                0.812              0.812                0.906                0.938
 7 P02     OPA   "chairs "                0.938              0.781                0.875                0.938
 8 P02     OPA   "targets"                0.781              0.906                0.875                0.906
 9 P03     EBA   "chairs "                0.719              0.938                0.906                0.781
10 P03     EBA   "targets"                0.938              0.844                0.969                0.938
# … with 90 more rows
```

Code:

```
subj_means_index_Acc <- subjmeans_condition %>% 
                      select(subject, site, category, orientation, direction, mAcc) %>% 
                      unite("condition", orientation, direction) %>% 
                      spread(condition, mAcc) 

subj_means_index_Acc <- subj_means_index_Acc %>% 
  mutate(inv_eff_facing = (1-inverted_facing) - (1-upright_facing),                       
         inv_eff_nonfacing =(1-inverted_nonFacing) - (1-upright_nonFacing)) %>%            
  mutate(inv_eff_fac_nf = inv_eff_facing - inv_eff_nonfacing)
```

Comment: Look at the spaces in the header row.  Your variable is not `inverted_spacing` but `inverted_spacing    ` (or similar: I haven't counted the spaces).

Comment: you could use `janitor::clean_names()` to get rid of the spaces.

Comment: If you don't want to use another package, this will remove the spaces, too: `names(subj_means_index_Acc) <- gsub(" ", "", names(subj_means_index_Acc))`

Comment: Or if you prefer `dplyr` syntax: `data %>% rename_with(.cols = everything(), ~stringr::str_trim(.))`

Comment: Thank you all. The `names(subj_means_index_Acc) <- gsub(" ", "", names(subj_means_index_Acc))` solved the problem. It was indeed about the spaces.

Comment: Looking at the solution I am a bit confused if this should be a Question with an Answer or a 'typo' flag. the problem was solved and pretty sure Eva Balgova wouldn't be the first or last person with this kind of problem...